# How to configure DB setup with out password in jboss standalone.xml configuration

Tags: java, jboss, server, db2, jboss6.x

Previously I provided with user name and password and it was working fine. Now The Db side provided access with username **only**. I mean Username alone I can able to db server and not require password..
Fyr:
jboss path :

```
\jboss-eap-6.2\standalone\configuration\standalone.xml
<user-name>prabhu</user-name>
<password>x1234</password>
```

Now If try to provide only username, I am unable to connect Db. your help highly appreciated.

```
<datasource jta="true" jndi-name="java:/repdb" pool-name="db2_pool_repdb_amlinst" enabled="true" use-java-context="true" use-ccm="true">
    <connection-url>jdbc:db2://01.83.42.122:50000/PRODDB:currentSchema=XYZ;</connection-url>
    <driver-class>com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver</driver-class>
    <driver>db2</driver>
    <security>
        <user-name>prabhu</user-name>
        <password>x1234</password>
    </security>
    <validation>
        <validate-on-match>false</validate-on-match>
        <background-validation>false</background-validation>
    </validation>
    <statement>
        <share-prepared-statements>false</share-prepared-statements>
    </statement>
</datasource>
```

Comment: What do you get when you remove `<password>x1234</password>` ?

Comment: Im getting error as unable establish connection..

Comment: please add the stack trace to your question

Comment: Why has the "DB side" only provided a user name? As far as I'm aware all DBs have a password.